# what is the nm-applet and why does it take so much memory?

Tags: memory, memory-usage, default-programs

I was wondering why my memory useage was so high, what is this thing that take a whopping 1.2GB of memory.

Please and thank you.

Comment: What version of network-manager-gnome are you running?  There was an issue with the version included in an elementary-art ppa -- I'd rule out that you don't have that one, first.

Comment: @jgbelacqua yes I do have that installed! how do I remove it?

Comment: I deleted mine manually from /etc/apt/sources.list.d .  Look/grep for elementary , delete it (or backup + delete), and then apt-get update.  At that point, I actually removed the entire package and reinstalled it while I was connected to wireless.

Comment: @jgbelacqua its not in the list and when i do sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome/maverick it complains saying it is installed

Comment: When you do `apt-cache show network-manager-gnome`, does you have just that (correct) entry?

Comment: Also, what version 'buntu are you running?

Comment: I am running 10.10 I managed to fix it by looking at comment 50 in this link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/684599 and checking to see if I had the issue with the command you linked. I am back to normal now. thanks!

Comment: jgbelacqua put it in the form of a question. I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced the same on my 12.04 installation. After a little research it appeared that it was just a GUI component (representing the icon in the status bar), and killing it will *not* affect the network connections.

SO I killed it and launched a new one from my terminal. Resource manager showed an immediate drop of 1.5 GB of RAM consumption.

```
killall nm-applet
nm-applet &
```

Answer (score 3):

nm-applet is the NetworkManager Applet:

[image: NetworkManager Applet]

It is not supposed to be using this much memory. There is currently an open [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/684599) for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the version of network-manager-gnome included in an elementary-art ppa -- I'd rule out that you don't have that one, first.

I deleted mine manually from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` . Look or grep for elementary , delete it (or backup + delete), and then `apt-get update`.

For myself, at that point I actually removed the entire package and reinstalled it while I was connected to wireless (without dropping connectivity that I could tell).

This command will show you what versions you have available:

```
 apt-cache show network-manager-gnome
```

You can also see the installation preference with 
`apt-cache policy network-manager-gnome` .

From the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/684599) :
This is marked as fixed in Natty(11.04).  For Maverick (10.10), you can downgrade to the official package from the archive with
 `sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome/maverick` .

Answer (score 0):

It's the Network Manager applet.  1.2GB does seem a bit high, though.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Mitch This answers have the question, sort of. Arguably this should be removed, but [it should not be a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments).