# Is it normal for nm-applet to use 1,5Gig of ram?

Tags: network-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the nm-applet and why does it take so much memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30007/what-is-the-nm-applet-and-why-does-it-take-so-much-memory)

nm-applet suspiciously uses about 1 gig of RAM on Ubuntu 10.10.

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: mine uses 50-60MBs.  Still seems like an obscene amount, but fwiw, that's my nm-applet

Comment: Short answer: no

Answer (score 2):

Did you recently get an update for network-manager? There's a known problem with the latest upgrade that causes a memory leak in nm-applet.

Search for network-manager-gnome and see if you have the 0.8.2 version. If you have it, revert back to 0.8.1 and block that version for not being upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is using 3.9 MB right now on an ethernet connection with 10.10 64-bit. 1.5 Gigs is obviously way too much. Try the obvious things like restarting your machine or killing the process
?